# Get ID of Rails object as soon as it's created using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create multiple objects called "baseRules" in jQuery by calling post requests to my Rails controllers. Nested inside of this creation of objects are a subset of rules, called "matchTypes", that belong to the main rules. I need to assign a foreign_id to this subset for it to work correctly though. Is there any way to get the ID of the main rules object as soon as it's created in jQuery?

Here is my Javascript code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < baseRules.length; i++) {
    $.post('/rule_types', {
        name: baseRules[i][0],
        matchFlag: baseRules[i][1]
    }, function () {
        if (baseRules[i][1]) {
            for (var k = 0; k < baseRules[i][2].length; k++) {
                $.post('/match_types', {
                    name: matchType[i][2][k],
                    rule_type_id: ? ? ? ?
                }, function () {

                });
            }

        }
    });
}
```

And here are my controller methods:

```
class RuleTypesController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @ruleType = RuleType.new
        @ruleType.name = params[:name]
        @ruleType.matchFlag = params[:matchFlag]
        respond_to do |format|
            if @ruleType.save
                format.html{redirect_to root_path}
                format.js{}
            else
                format.html{}
                format.js{}
            end
        end
    end
end

class MatchTypesController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @matchType = MatchType.new
        @matchType.name = params[:name]
        matchType.rule_types_id = params[:rule_type_id] 
        respond_to do |format|
            if @ruleType.save
                format.html{redirect_to root_path}
                format.js{}
            else
                format.html{}
                format.js{}
            end
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: there is nothing shown in your code regarding jQuery creating anything. You are going to need to add more explanation. Also AJAX success handlers in your code have no response arguments

Answer (score 1):

In respect to your question (the extra "frills" can be addressed after), in order to receive the `id` of a newly created object, you should be able to capture it with the ajax:success request.

---

**Ajax**

Your flow is slightly complicated ([Ajax is asynchronous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))), meaning that if you want to use the data you receive, you may have to use an ajax callback (not as complicated as it sounds)

If you create a new record, Rails will ALWAYS fire back a response. Inside this response, you can access the `id` attribute of the newly created record, allowing you to access the new ID for your object:

```
for (var i = 0; i < baseRules.length; i++) {
    $.post('/rule_types', {
        name: baseRules[i][0],
        matchFlag: baseRules[i][2]
    }, function (data) {
        var returnedData = JSON.parse(data);
        if (baseRules[i][3]) {
            for (var k = 0; k < baseRules[i][2].length; k++) {
                $.post('/match_types', {
                    name: matchType[i][2][k],
                    rule_type_id: returnedData.id //Calls the original "ID" of the returned post
                }, function () {

                });
            }

        }
    }, dataType: "json");
}
```

This will give you the ability to determine JSON responses in your controller:

```
#app/controllers/rules_types_controller.rb
class RuleTypesController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :js, :json, :html

    def create
        @ruleType = RuleType.new
        @ruleType.name = params[:name]
        @ruleType.matchFlag = params[:matchFlag]
        @ruleType.save

        respond_with @ruleType
        end
    end
end
```

---

**Response**

Although I think you'll make progress with what I've posted, you'll want to look at how you're using the `$.post` function. Although it *should* work as you have it now, you need to appreciate that if you try and use ajax functionality `synchronously`, it will likely [freeze your UI](http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/javascript/ajax-async-false-freeze-ui/) whilst the request completes

The way to solve this is to use an Ajax callback. We've done this before:

```
function fetch(link, data, response, type = "script") {
   $.post(link, data, response(data), dataType: type);
}

for (var i = 0; i < baseRules.length; i++) {
    fetch('/rule_types', {
        name: baseRules[i][0],
        matchFlag: baseRules[i][2]
    }, function (data) {
        var returnedData = JSON.parse(data);
        if (baseRules[i][3]) {
            for (var k = 0; k < baseRules[i][2].length; k++) {
                fetch('/match_types', {
                    name: matchType[i][2][k],
                    rule_type_id: returnedData.id //Calls the original "ID" of the returned post
                });
            }

        }
    }, "json");
}
```

This *should* make it so that your ajax calls are truly asynchronous - updating only when they have the data returned from the server. I can re-factor this if you'd prefer

Comment: The first part of your response makes sense to me--I didn't think about just sending the ID back in the success function. The only thing is that the value of i in the for loop doesn't seem to increment inside the Ajax request (it's always stuck as the length of the array). Also, I tried rewriting the code for the second part and received an error on that function "Unexpected token =" on the fetch function.

Comment: Hmmm okay! Can you explain about the incrementing issue? How would you expect it to grow?

Comment: In the success function, I need to be able to use the value of i as it increments but because the callback triggers after the for loop has completed, the i will always be the length of the array.